Joomla-5 - How do I get the h1-header for the category blog material in the template?
Blog categories such as "News". It contains a list of materials.
How do I get the  title of the material in the template?
In the original in com_content/tmpl/article/default.php - the title is displayed like this:
echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading'));
but of course it doesn't work in the template
If I write this code, then the parent's title will be displayed - "News"
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams(); echo $params->get('page_heading');  
The closest thing to what is needed is to displayed the TITLE of the material
$document = &JFactory::getDocument(); echo $document->title;
Can you tell me how to do it correctly? Thanks
